# Complex random selection conditions

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I'm still somewhat of a beginner in python, and my latest project has been a wordle bot, using only basic libraries (random, time). In one specific part of the project, I need to generate a new word based on knowledge known from another word. This is the code I am using right now. Some of the names may be confusing, so feel free to ask me.

---

```
while cmet == False:
    n_guess = []
    count = 0 
    for i in ne_guess:
      n_guess.append(i)
    ne_guess = random.choice(words)
    for i in comp_guess:
      if comp_guess[count] == 'green':
        if n_guess[count] == 'green':
          criteria = True
      elif comp_guess[count] == 'yellow':

        if n_guess[count] != 'yellow' and comp_guess[count] in n_guess:
          criteria2 = True
      elif comp_guess[count] == 'gray':
        if n_guess[count] not in comp_guess[count]:
          criteria3 = True
      if criteria == True and criteria2 == True and criteria3 == True:
        cmet = True
        count+=1
        print(n_guess)
        print(c_word)
        time.sleep(2)
      else:
        ne_guess = random.choice(words)
```

---

essentially, if a letter is "green" that means it is in that word, and in that spot. if a letter is yellow, it is in the word, but not in the spot. If the letter is gray, that means the word does not contain that letter. Basic wordle stuff. When I run, no matter what I try to change, the code continuously evaluates the same word, instead of changing the word which is evaluated.
what i've tried:
printing different components to check where im going wrong. output:A new word is generated, but the same word is evaluated.
changing the code a billion times. output: error persists no matter the formatting.
I would appreciate some help. I am happy to comment full code if anyone needs it.

Comment: Instead of dumping your entire code here (which may be quite extensive), please create a [mre], including hardcoded values for all variables, the imports you are using, etc., so that we can recreate the problem. For example, we have no idea what the contents of `ne_guess` or `comp_guess` are.

Comment: @MattDMo Ive considered this, and frusteratingly enough, certain fundamental parts of the code im making are nescessart in this aspect of the project. After rewriting the script with shortening it in mind, the results are not only different from the main projects, but overall just completely different from what I am referring to here. I can persist if you deem it very nescessary. Apologies if i am misunderstanding anything, this is literally my first post lol.

Comment: a [mre] contains the smallest amount of code necessary to reproduce your condition. It may include a few (or more than a few) more lines than what you've shown us so far, but unless we can reproduce what's happening, using the values that you are using, then we'll mostly just be guessing. It doesn't need to have the entire functionality of your whole program, just enough to make this part run the way it's currently running for you.

Comment: @MattDMo after some more attempts at making an mre, Im not quite sure this question is right for stack overflow, as it seems a little too specific to this problem.I may take it down soon, but I really appreciate your patience in dealing with my lack of knowledge in stack overflows system.